# Property 'loginToken' does not exist on type '{ loginToken: string; } | { error: Error; } | { username: string; password: string; }'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

I am trying to create a reducer using typescript/ redux and I am facing this error

```
Property 'loginToken' does not exist on type '{ loginToken: string; } | { error: Error; } | { username: string; password: string; }'.
  Property 'loginToken' does not exist on type '{ error: Error; }'
```

My reducer is as following:

```
export default (state = userState, action: UsersActions) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.USER_LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    case ActionTypes.USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        loginToken: action.payload.loginToken,
        isLoading: false,
      };
```

My action types:

```
export interface UserLoginRequest extends Action {
  type: typeof ActionTypes.USER_LOGIN_REQUEST; // !! here we assign the string literal type of the constant
  payload: {
    username: string;
    password: string;
  };
}

export interface UserLoginSuccess extends Action {
  type: typeof ActionTypes.USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS; // !! here we assign the string literal type of the constant
  payload: {
    loginToken: string;
  };
}

export interface UserLoginFailure extends Action {
  type: typeof ActionTypes.USER_LOGIN_FAILURE; // !! here we assign the string literal type of the constant
  payload: {
    error: Error;
  };
}

export interface User {
  username: string;
  password: string;
  loginToken: string;
  loginError?: Error;
  status?: number;
}

export type UsersActions = 
| UserLoginSuccess
| UserLoginFailure
| UserLoginRequest;
```

Action types are an enum like this:

```
enum ActionTypes {
    USER_LOGIN_REQUEST = 'request',
    USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS = 'success',
    USER_LOGIN_FAILURE = 'failure',
};
```

Maybe I am not getting something regarding Typescript so that's why? if any resources or insights can be provided that would be appreciated.

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the error?

Comment: this one :
 loginToken: action.payload.loginToken,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `UsersActions` can be one of three things - a UserLoginSuccess, a UserLoginFailure, or a UserLoginRequest - it's a Union Type.

In the "Success" case, *you* know that the login token will exist, and that the type is a UserLoginSuccess - but TypeScript doesn't have any way of knowing this, so it's telling you that you may be trying to get the `loginToken` property from (e.g.) a `UserLoginFailure` type.

The solution is that [you've got to narrow the type when you want to work with it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#working-with-union-types). Since there's no common properties on your union type that you could switch on, the only way I can think to do this would be to cast the payload to the correct type:

```
case ActionTypes.USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    isAuthenticated: true,
    loginToken: (action.payload as UserLoginSuccess).loginToken,
    isLoading: false,
  };
```

### Edit

Sorry, I just re-read your question and noticed that there's a better solution - when you're creating your union types, you're using `typeof` for the action type -

```
export interface UserLoginRequest extends Action {
  type: typeof ActionTypes.USER_LOGIN_REQUEST;
  // ...
}
```

So `type` will be the type of whatever that property is - but I'm guessing what you actually want to do is make it into a known value?

I don't know what `ActionsTypes` is defined as, but if this was an `enum` -

```
enum ActionTypes {
    USER_LOGIN_REQUEST = 'request',
    USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS = 'success',
    USER_LOGIN_FAILURE = 'failure',
};
```

Then you could change the type definitions to use the enum type instead -

```
interface UserLoginRequest extends Action {
  type: ActionTypes.USER_LOGIN_REQUEST;
  payload: {
    username: string;
    password: string;
  };
}
```

Now, when you switch on the `type`, TS will correctly narrow the payload for you -

```
switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
        console.log(action.payload.loginToken); // TS is happy!
        break;

    default:
        console.log('NOT A SUCCESS ACTION');
}
```

[Here's a quick repro in TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=51&ssc=2&pln=44&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIILMA9iZBvZQ5AKAF9jiIQBXAWzQ2xABUBPABwgGd9ijkAqgGUAogCUA+gBkA8gHEAkgDkJYkQEUBIoc2QBeZAHIoEAI7VuYQwBo+RYeOnzlEoQIDC77UP1Gu1BCQuLhs7QgdJWUUVADFUBSkBNV9DeGAAG2oTUNIAbgpQSFhEFAEuaCksAHNQMTMLLjBkCAAPSBAAEx50TBxeQjAOCAAuBl6WIa4AOginaNUNLR18wnY4VnSsOA7RvDDkanKoEDhaEeRGqFAqlaI14IB3LCgdi7ArkBu7PLIC8Gh4EhBEdKjUQEIAkEeK12l0xkx+shBpxRj0mGxONNZlEXG5PN5bmsNltXnt+JswcwsABrKijS7XW4-cjEQoAkrAirVUAxOAZLIoGFUOFovpkpFDVGMHAY7gzUSRZyxeKJNSE9abba7fbQKDPUYiKB6qBM-Is5GlI5cUUgHgGYgAH05UFBoAhgW4XEdztdIF5-JM3rKXLBdXMlnyxAQOEayEQ41Gwag1ultt84oGkvhMsm8scOJUeK8QiEtn4RM1pP25O5LBpdKMa3AIX25B+xC4D2AYAQAAtkAAKeNMKYWgCUiMICDg5WzE0xecV8yL3mG1aI0dtWHSECmFKHqamFZJe9rVNpIDHt34hAARiY4NTI-wOhB4NR0mA1zeNzHt7v90MJQZF0VBkBXEs0HcZgFBkJRDCvMggA)

Comment: Thanks for your very clear explanation behind the error, I will definitely check how to work with union types with more context now :)

Comment: This is not necessarily correct – this is exactly how a discriminated union is supposed to work – https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions

I think something else is at play here. The example in the original post "should work", just not sure what's wrong yet.

Comment: Also, discrimination works even with `typeof`, like in the original post. Try e.g. `type: typeof ActionTypes.USER_LOGIN_REQUEST;` – still works.

Comment: @rsmeral - I think it might depend how `ActionTypes` is defined; if it's a `const` then the discrimination fails, but it's ok if it's an `enum` - see: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-f2il7?file=/index.ts

Comment: @gerrod I think you got it! 
@RowanX – could you edit your question to clarify what `ActionTypes` is? Might help future readers.

Also – it can work even with the object literal style, if you append `as const`.
As in `const ActionTypes = {
  USER_LOGIN_REQUEST: "request",
  USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS: "success",
  USER_LOGIN_FAILURE: "failure"
} as const;`

Comment: Yes sure, thanks for all the insights guys
It's an enum as @gerrod mentioned, I will update the question